# Map region doesn't fit in MapView of Titanium when catch event 'regionChanged'

Tags: android-mapview, titanium

I write a demo mapview in Titanium (iPhone). Here's the code I get from KitchenSink:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
var annotation = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
    latitude:42.334537,
    longitude:-71.170101,
    title:"Boston College",
    subtitle:'Newton Campus, Chestnut Hill, MA',
    animate:true,
    leftButton:'../images/atlanta.jpg'
});

var boston = {latitude:42.334537,longitude:-71.170101,latitudeDelta:0.010, longitudeDelta:0.018};

//
// CREATE MAP VIEW
//
var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region: boston,
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true,
    annotations:[annotation]
});

win.add(mapview);
```

It runs well on both iPhone Simulator as well as in real phone.
The problem is, when I catch event 'regionChanged', the map region is wrong. My code is:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

var annotation = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
    latitude:42.334537,
    longitude:-71.170101,
    title:"Boston College",
    subtitle:'Newton Campus, Chestnut Hill, MA',
    animate:true,
    leftButton:'../images/atlanta.jpg'
});

var boston = {latitude:42.334537,longitude:-71.170101,latitudeDelta:0.010, longitudeDelta:0.018};

//
// CREATE MAP VIEW
//
var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region: boston,
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true,
    annotations:[annotation]
});

win.add(mapview);

// map view click event listener
mapview.addEventListener('regionChanged',function(evt)
{

});
```

In this event, I even didn't write anything. In Simulator, it works well as the first case, but in real phone, the map zoom level is suddenly maximum. Although I set latitudeDelta=1, the zoom level of map is still zoom-in maximum as if latitudeDelta=0.001.

So, what's the root of this bug? Anyone can help me?

Comment: Are you saying it works in simulator but not on real device? The end of the question starts to get confusing

Comment: ah yes, in 2 situation, the mapview zoom in Simulator is correct. But the problem occurs in real device in the last case. I've just edited question to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I found the root of this bug. Just need to set `regionFit:true` and zoom level of map is correct.